# Is there are anyway to animate this like a running conveyor belt?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, svg, graphics

I need to animate this so that it'll look like a running conveyor belt, is there are any way to achieve it?

```js
const cx = 50;
const cy = 50;
const width = 40;
const radius = 100; // CV size
const TwoPi = Math.PI * 0.5;

const circ = TwoPi * radius;
const height = circ / 4; // Roller counts
const parent = document.getElementById("bend");

for (let i = 0; i < circ; i += height) {
    let seg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
    
    let rs = (i / circ) * TwoPi;
    let re = ((i + height) / circ) * TwoPi;
    
    let ss = Math.sin(rs);
    let cs = Math.cos(rs);
    let se = Math.sin(re);
    let ce = Math.cos(re);
    
    seg.setAttribute("d",
        `M${(cs * radius) + cx},${(ss * radius) + cy}` +
        `A${radius},${radius} ${((re - rs) / Math.PI) * 180},0,1 ${(ce * radius) + cx},${(se * radius) + cy}` +
        `L${(ce * (radius - width)) + cx},${(se * (radius - width)) + cy}` +
        `A${radius - width},${radius - width} ${((re - rs) / Math.PI) * -180},0,0 ${(cs * (radius - width)) + cx},${(ss * (radius - width)) + cy}z`
    );
    
    seg.setAttribute("fill", "url(#grad2)");
    seg.setAttribute("stroke", "#008000");
    
    parent.appendChild(seg);
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="transform: rotate(-90deg)">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad2" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="40%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#008000;stop-opacity:1"/>
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#c7fdc7;stop-opacity:1"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
    <g id="bend"></g>
</svg>
```

Here's the [preview](https://codepen.io/chococonya/pen/YzJaxpw) of the above code, and this is the running animation [example](https://codepen.io/chococonya/pen/oNMJVGz).

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution (run the snippet below):

```js
const drawSegment = (fromAngle, toAngle, innerRadius, outerRadius, centerX, centerY) => {
  const svg = d3.select('svg');
  const x1 = centerX + innerRadius * Math.sin(fromAngle);
  const y1 = centerY - innerRadius * Math.cos(fromAngle);
  const x2 = centerX + outerRadius * Math.sin(fromAngle);
  const y2 = centerY - outerRadius * Math.cos(fromAngle);
  const x3 = centerX + outerRadius * Math.sin(toAngle);
  const y3 = centerY - outerRadius * Math.cos(toAngle);
  const x4 = centerX + innerRadius * Math.sin(toAngle);
  const y4 = centerY - innerRadius * Math.cos(toAngle);
  const path = `M ${x1},${y1} L ${x2},${y2} A ${outerRadius},${outerRadius} 0 0 1 ${x3},${y3} L ${x4},${y4} A ${innerRadius}, ${innerRadius} 0 0 0 ${x1},${y1} Z`;
  
  svg.append('path')
    .attr('d', path)
    .attr('stroke', '#008000')
    .attr('fill', 'url(#grad)')
}

const a = Math.PI / 8;
let start = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  d3.select('svg').selectAll('path').remove();
  if (start < 1) {
    start += 0.02;
  }
  else
    start = 0;

  if (start > 0) {
    drawSegment(0, start * a, 50, 80, 20, 100);
  }
  for (let i = start; i < 4; i++) {
    drawSegment(a * i, Math.min((i + 1) * a, a * 4), 50, 80, 20, 100);
  }
}, 50);
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="200" height="120">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="40%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#008000;stop-opacity:1"/>
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#c7fdc7;stop-opacity:1"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
    <g id="bend"></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thankyou, this is a great help to me. Can please let me know how can I change the size and space between each segment?

Comment: @Choco you can modify `drawSegment` parameters the way you wish (`fromAngle`, `toAngle`, `innerRadius`, `outerRadius`). Note that angles are given in radians

Comment: hi, can pls let me know how can i reverse the animation? it's currently from 0 to 90 but when i try to modify from 90 to 0 it's a mess

Comment: @Choco see my new answer

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version made with a slice of a circle that is repeated. The animation is made with the [`<animateTransform>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateTransform) element.

Less calculations and more construction.

```html
<svg width="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad" x1="60%" y1="60%" x2="90%" y2="90%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#008000" stop-opacity="1"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#c7fdc7" stop-opacity="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="m1">
      <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" fill="white"/>
    </mask>
    <circle id="c1" cx="0" cy="0" r="70" fill="none"
      stroke="url(#grad)" stroke-width="28" pathLength="360"
      stroke-dasharray="19 360" />
  </defs>
  <g mask="url(#m1)">
    <g transform="translate(50 150) rotate(-180)" >
      <g>
        <circle id="c1" cx="0" cy="0" r="70" fill="none"
          stroke="darkgreen" stroke-width="30" />
        <use href="#c1"/>
        <use href="#c1" transform="rotate(20)"/>
        <use href="#c1" transform="rotate(40)"/>
        <use href="#c1" transform="rotate(60)"/>
        <use href="#c1" transform="rotate(80)"/>
        <use href="#c1" transform="rotate(100)"/>
        <use href="#c1" transform="rotate(120)"/>
        <use href="#c1" transform="rotate(140)"/>
        <use href="#c1" transform="rotate(160)"/>
        <animateTransform
          attributeName="transform"
          attributeType="XML"
          type="rotate"
          from="0"
          to="80"
          dur="5s"
          repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reverse animation:

```js
const drawSegment = (fromAngle, toAngle, 
    innerRadius, outerRadius, centerX, centerY) => {
    const svg = d3.select('svg');
  const x1 = centerX + innerRadius * Math.sin(fromAngle);
  const y1 = centerY - innerRadius * Math.cos(fromAngle);
  const x2 = centerX + outerRadius * Math.sin(fromAngle);
  const y2 = centerY - outerRadius * Math.cos(fromAngle);
  const x3 = centerX + outerRadius * Math.sin(toAngle);
  const y3 = centerY - outerRadius * Math.cos(toAngle);
  const x4 = centerX + innerRadius * Math.sin(toAngle);
  const y4 = centerY - innerRadius * Math.cos(toAngle);
  const path = `M ${x1},${y1} L ${x2},${y2} A ${outerRadius},${outerRadius} 0 0 1 ${x3},${y3} L ${x4},${y4} A ${innerRadius}, ${innerRadius} 0 0 0 ${x1},${y1} Z`;
  
  svg.append('path')
    .attr('d', path)
    .attr('stroke', '#0F0')
    .attr('fill', 'url(#grad)')
}

const seg = Math.PI / 8;
let delta = 0, start, end;

setInterval(() => {
    d3.select('svg').selectAll('path').remove();
    if (delta < 1) {
    delta += 0.02;
  }
  else {
    delta = 0;
  }
  if (delta > 0) {
    start = seg * (4 - delta);
    end = seg * 4;
    drawSegment(start, end, 50, 80, 20, 100);
  }
  else {
    start = seg * 4;
  }
  while (start > 0)     {
    end = start;
    start = Math.max (0, end - seg);
    drawSegment(start, end, 50, 80, 20, 100);
  }
}, 100);
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="200" height="120">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="40%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#008000;stop-opacity:1"/>
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#c7fdc7;stop-opacity:1"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
    <g id="bend"></g>
</svg>
```